# Java write to Stdin

Tags: java, jruby, stdin

So I have imported a jruby interpreter as a library to run an external ruby application. However I need to interact with the ruby application in some way. Right now I have the ruby application outputting information on stdout and requesting user options in stdin.

So if I want java to be able to handle inserting the options instead of a user, I'll need a way that I can write to the stdin somehow from java to choose the options. Does anyone know how I can do this? Or even a better way to do this?

I'm calling jruby like so:

```
String[] newargs = new String[2];
newargs[0] = "-S";
newargs[1]  = "path_to_some_rubyfile.rb"
org.jruby.Main jruby = new org.jruby.Main();
ruby.main(newargs);
```

The ruby app outputs stuff like this:

```
How do you feel today?
(1) Happy
(2) Sad
```

And then waits for the user input to enter 1 or 2.
But I would like Java to input these options instead of having a user do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not overly familiar with JRuby, I honestly would have thought that it automatically wraps System.in. Check to see that such an option does exist. Otherwise my personal choice would be to simply start a new Process("ruby") and use the streams provided by that.

Regards
md_5

Answer (score 0):

Jruby does have a way to contruct it by specifying an inputstream and two output streams, however what I found to work better was to create a PipedOutPutstream that writes to a PipedInputStream and you set the System input to the PipedInputStream like so:

```
PipedOutputStream inwriter = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream input = new PipedInputStream(inwriter);
System.setIn(input);
inwriter.write("1\n".getBytes());
```